# window.setInterval('string;', 1);

Tags: javascript

I have seen the following working! setinterval call.

```
window.setInterval('checkhash();', 1);
```

Any idea why this is working?

normaly it is like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
      do something
},1000);


function checkhash(){ };
```

Comment: What's exactly the question here ? The first one, while bad because it  asks the engine to repetitively eval the string, do work (if checkhash is a function).

Comment: I do not understand why the first statement is working. If I copy it to my work i will get an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have several options:

1) hand over a string which is then evaluated (bad - never do this!)

```
window.setInterval('checkhash()', 4);
```

This basically runs an evaluation on the string like `eval('checkhash()')`.

**Important to know, is that it is evaluated in the global context, so the following will *fail*:**

```
(function(){
    function test(){alert("foo")};
    function test2(){alert("bar")};

    // will fail
    setTimeout("test()",1000);


    // will work
    setTimeout(test2,1000);

})();
```

The first timeout will produce an `Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined`, because `test()` is only known in the context of your anonymous function, but not in the global space:
[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/F4p52/)

2) hand over a function reference (the preferred way)

```
window.setInterval(checkhash, 4);
```

3) hand over an anonymous function (used, when you need to hand over parameters)

```
setInterval(function(){
      checkhash(param1,param2);
},4);
```

Doing the following (common beginners mistake) is possible too:

```
window.setInterval(checkhash(), 4);
```

This will *call* the function immediately and hand over the *return value* to the timeout to be executed after the specified amount of time.

Important notes:

- the execution is asynchronous - the javscript engine will continue with the execution of the rest of your js code.
- The minimal timeout is `4` ms as per spec, so basically 0-3 will give you an interval of at least `4ms` (depending on the scheduler of course).
- You have no guarantee that the timeout will trigger in exactly that amount of time. It might even be completely discarded in some very rare circumstances.

A very good reading is [John Resig's article about timers](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).

[MDN setTimeout documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

this should be like,

```
window.setInterval(checkhash, 1);
```

remove your quotes, and do like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the all the JavaScript `eval` situations, which is not a good practice, if you use string as the first parameter, it automatically get converted to a anonymous function like this:

```
Function('checkhash();')
```

So why not passing the first parameter as a function, which is the other alternative and more reasonable one.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    checkhash();
}, 1);
```

or simply:

```
window.setInterval(checkhash, 1);
```

the only problem this way is sometimes you need to use [JavaScript closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) to keep you your variable values stable.

Comment: I have seen it here: http://reasons.screenagers.at/js/main.js
cant find closures in point of the function

Comment: @hamburger: waiting for that here...